# MarkerClusterPlus Cluster Size Format

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am using the Google Maps API and MarkerClusterPlus v3 to render out many pins on a map and then cluster them.  The problem is the clusters might have a very large number like 10000 in them, and so I'd like to format the larger numbers to say "10k" instead of "10000" so it's cleaner and fits on the cluster images.

Has anyone done this? I've done some searching and haven't found any methods to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know easy way to do this, but you can try to experiment with changing marker's values using `markerCluster.setCalculator` function like [here](https://nooshu.github.io/blog/2012/10/03/marker-cluster-calculator-for-google-maps-v3/).

Just add a condition you need before returning the value (inside `setCalculator`), eg.:

```
        if (count >= 1000) {
            var short = (count / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k';
            return {
                text: short,
                index: index
            }
        } else {
            return {
                text: count,
                index: index
            };
        }
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. I did it a bit different but the idea came from your answer. I'm using the marker-clusterer-plus npm package so I can't add code in but it allows me to overwrite any function by passing it in the options object, so I just rewrote it, passed it in, and added in your conditionals and it works like a charm.